# CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, cidr

I am trying to create an application load balancer. To do this, I need two subnets.

The current subnet CIDR block is 172.31.0.0/16. Every time I try to create a new CIDR block for the 2nd subnet, I keep getting this error:

```
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR
```

I am not a big networking guy. So I am struggling with this.

I've tried googling but I'm struggling to comprehend what to actually input.

Comment: What is the CIDR of your VPC? What is the CIDR of the subnet you are attempting to add?

Comment: The CIDR that is allocated to the VPC 172.31.0.0/16. While the subnet CIDR is the same. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

A `/16` CIDR is an extremely large range to allocate to a subnet.

Start by taking a look at the CIDR allocated to the whole VPC. It is likely to be something like `172.31.0.0/16`. A `/16` range has 65,536 IP addresses.

Then, take a look at the subnets. They are likely to be something like `172.31.0.0/24` and `172.31.1.0/24`. A `/24` range has 256 IP addresses.

It is safer to always use a CIDR calculator such as: https://cidr.xyz/

For more information about private IP address ranges, see: [Private network - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

Comment: The CIDR that is allocated to the VPC 172.31.0.0/16. While the subnet CIDR is the same. What should I do?

Comment: It means that the existing subnet is occupying all addressable space in the VPC. Do you have existing resources in the VPC? If not, you could delete the subnet and recreate it with a smaller range. Failing that, you can add more IP addresses to the VPC by going to the VPC in the management console and choosing **Actions / Edit CIDRs**. You can add an additional range, such as `172.30.0.0/16`. Then you could create new subnets like `172.30.0.0/24` and `172.30.1.0/24`.

Comment: Okay, I will delete the subnet. What are examples of smaller ranges?

Comment: See my answer -- people typically use `/24` ranges for subnets (256 addresses), or you could make smaller ones such as `/25` (128 addresses), etc.

Comment: Okay. I have created the new subnet and it's CIDR is 172.31.0.0/24. For the 2nd subnet, what would it be for it to go through? Thanks John

Comment: The next logical range is `172.31.1.0/24` -- this represents all IP addresses starting with `172.31.1.x`.